# JavaScript methods one works the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

Why does this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#listF').on('change', function(){
    var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
});
    });
</script>


<select name="" id="listF" size="5">
    <option value="01">001</option>
    <option value="02">002</option>
    <option value="03">003</option>
    <option value="04">004</option>
    <option value="05">005</option>
    <option value="06">006</option>
    <option value="07">007</option>
    <option value="08">008</option>
    <option value="09">009</option>
    <option value="10">010</option>
</select>
```

and this does not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function centerNumber(){
    var n = 5,
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
}
</script>


<select name="" id="listF" size="5" onchange="centerNumber()">
    <option value="01">001</option>
    <option value="02">002</option>
    <option value="03">003</option>
    <option value="04">004</option>
    <option value="05">005</option>
    <option value="06">006</option>
    <option value="07">007</option>
    <option value="08">008</option>
    <option value="09">009</option>
    <option value="10">010</option>
```

I prefer the second method as it can be used plenty of times not just one. In the first method you must copy/paste the code at each time you need to change. The second method seems cleaner.

What I mean in it doesn't work is that it does not centre. The JavaScript seems to fail to work.

Comment: Please define "does not work"

Comment: @ThomasStets - I updated my question. The JavaScript seems to fail.

Comment: Please define "seems to fail"

Comment: @Alnitak - The JavaScript doesn't load or do what it is suppose to do i.e. center the the selection in the centre.

Comment: Are these 2 different file or you're calling jquery.min.js 2 times?

Answer (score 4):

The value of `this` depends on how a function is called.

In the first example the anonymous function expression you pass to `on` is the event handler, so when it gets called it is in the context of the element.

In the second example, `onchange` is the event handler (which doesn't use `this` at all) and it calls `centerNumber` with no context (so it gets the default context of `window`).

---

> I prefer the second method

Don't. Embedding JS in HTML and using globals is how we did things in the 90s. It is far cleaner to [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and package code into narrow scopes to avoid conflicts.

> as it can be used plenty of times not just one. In the first method you must copy/paste the code at each time you need to change.

That is not true. Just define a function first and reuse it.

```
function someFunction (event) { 
    /* do stuff */ 
};

jQuery('.someElements').on('change', someFunction);
jQuery('#anElement').on('click', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the second method - inline DOM0 event handlers are error prone and old-fashioned.    The specific problem you have is that you don't pass a correct `this` to the centering function.

By all means do put the handler in a separate named function so that it can be re-used on multiple elements (as you did in the second code) but then you should use jQuery to register it:

```
$('#listF').on('change', centerNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second script doesn't work because `this` doesn't point to the element.

In the event handler `this` is the element, but then you call a function so you lose the context. You can use the `call` method to specify the context for the function:

```
onchange="centerNumber.call(this)"
```

---

You can use the first approach with multiple elements also, just specify them in the selector. Example:

```
$('#listA,#listB,#listC,#listD,#listE,#listF').on('change', function(){
```

Using a class to target the elements makes it even easier, as you can set the same class on multiple elements.

Comment: @RobG I don't think that's correct if supplied inline - only as written in JS code.  AFAIK, anything supplied inline gets wrapped in an anonymous function wrapper, so the effect would be as if writing `function() { centerNumber; }`

Comment: I interpreted the first example as assignment in the function, not setting the attribute. :-( If added as a property, e.g. `document.getElementById('listF').onchange = centerNumber;`, then *this* will be set as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you will call centerNumber() method with 'this' as a parameter then this will work. e.g.,

```
<select name="" id="listF" size="5" onchange="centerNumber(this)">


<script type="text/javascript" >
    function centerNumber(which){
        var n = 5,
        i = which.selectedIndex,
        l = which.options.length;
        which.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
        which.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
        which.selectedIndex = i;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good advice. You can also do it without jQuery (or any library), some options:

```
  // Things that work in all browsers
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('listF').onchange = centerNumber;
  }

  // Place in a script element just before the closing body tag
  document.getElementById('listF').onchange = centerNumber;

  // Things that work in most, but not all, browsers
  // IE 8 and lower don't support addEventListener
  // There are plenty of cross-browser alternatives
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('listF').addEventListener('change', centerNumber, false);
  }
```

There are lots of questions and answers on SO about attaching event listeners. It doesn't take long before inline listeners become a headache, but for a simple site they're just fine.

Comment: no, inline listeners are really not fine.  They complicate the code and encourage poor practises, for example you can only invoke globally defined functions from inline code.